# Using color variables in WP Gutenberg color palette

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to use colors selected in the customizer to change the theme colors in the Gutenberg editor. I'm using metabox to set the theme colors. I'm missing something.

This is essentially what I'm trying to do. It doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
$primary = rwmb_meta( 'primary_color', [ 'object_type' => 'setting' ], 'site_settings' );

add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
    array(
        'name'  => __( 'Primary', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug'  => 'primary',
        'color' => '$primary',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are unnecessary quotes around the variable `'$primary'` so it sets the value of `color` to the variable name instead of the value of `$primary`.

Update to:

```php
$primary = rwmb_meta( 'primary_color', [ 'object_type' => 'setting' ], 'site_settings' );

add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
    array(
        'name'  => __( 'Primary', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug'  => 'primary',
        'color' => $primary, // remove the ''
    )
);
```